# Updating Powerpoint - Excel Link in Different Computer

Tags: excel, excel-2007, powerpoint

I have an excel file that linked to powerpoint slide, when I was working in different computer and trying change the value in excel file, the data didn't updated automatically in powerpoint slide. A message appear tell me that I need to update the links manually.

So, how to update the link between excel file and powerpoint in different computer automatically or "in one work"..???

need help...

thx in advanced....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To roll your own, you'd look at the Excel shape's .LinkFormat.SourceFullname property.
It will point to the location where PPT expects to find the file.

Move the file to wherever you want it and change .LinkFormatSourcefullname to the new full path to the file.  It must be the full path; relative paths won't work.

There's some VBA code to automate this here if the old path and new path are consistent:

Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm

Comment: Thank Steve..

Is there other way to do this without VBA code?

Comment: There's a links dialog box that, I think, will let you manually edit the links.  In PPT 2010 it's on File | Info and if there links, there'll be an Edit Links To files link on the right side of screen.  This allows you to choose another file, but I'm not sure whether it allows you to choose the content within the file to link to.

Comment: I've update the link via links dialog box and from the ribbon > prepare > edit link (ms.excel 2007) and change the new source file. But, it's really a huge works to do so, since excel doesn't let select multiple file and change the source of the file. I also try to update my computer name to appropriate the old directory from old computer, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: It's really down to the choice of doing it manually/tediously or using VBA to automate it.